# Ubuntu ntfsundelete on md0 software raid after fsck

Tags: ubuntu, fsck, undelete

System was failing and the colocation facility ran fsck -y on a raid that had some important data.  The result is a lost+found folder with 2 million files in it.  It is possible to get any of the files data back? I was looking into ntfsundelete, but I cannot find an answer on how to run it on a software raid.  It may also be a terrible idea, so any input would be helpful.

So far I have ziped and downloaded all of the files just to have a backup.  In windows 7 it cannot handle a directory with 2 million files in it.  Is there a browser that someone knows of as well to handle this?

Comment: What filesystem is the partition where fsck was run?

Comment: ext4 Ubuntu Software Raid.

Comment: See my answer below. do you have data backup? @Iscariot

Comment: why you mentioned Windows if this is an Ubuntu machine? Does that server still boot?

Answer (score 0):

The fact is a RAID should be ininfluent here, because RAID works on a lower level than partitions.

`ntfsundete` works only with NTFS partitions. Indeed, there is `extundelete` and other data recovery tools for ext4, but they won't help in this case, because files weren't deleted, but corrupted.

You should restore your data from backup then request an hardware check on system (disks, mobo, cables)